# Sylius commerce symfony 2

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, failed-installation, sylius

I need help about sylius commerce installation, acctualy
somewhere in the middle of instalation I get an error:

> [RuntimeException]
>   Running git clone https://github.com/bergie/create.git failed with 1

and all commands I did before was just :

> composer create-project sylius/sylius-standard -s dev

...
I dont know where to look for solution, so please if anyone could help me I will be very thankful.

Greetings

Comment: try `composer create-project sylius/sylius-standard my_project` to install last stable version (v0.17.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce this problem on my Linux machine, but it could be a problem on your system with Git.

Try installing a newer version of git (make sure to link the 'git' command to the new version):
https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: I will try that solution in a second

Comment: Seems like this was solution

Comment: Awesome :) Marking this answer as most helpful will help others solving similar problems faster. Good luck.